# How to update ActiveRecord Created_at Updated_at if feeding database from outside of active record?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, etl, talend

I'm building a rails app on top of an existing database, and am wondering how I ensure that the created_at updated_at fields that active record adds to migrations are updated and filled when loading the database from a non rails/activerecord etl tool like Talend? I am not using the activerecord created_at, but rather loading another date field from the etl tool.

Comment: I've looked elsewhere and cannot find a solution, i'm often using data from multiple sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I can find is: Set the date fields using the External tool. Talend Includes Date and Date-time functions, you can use Date-time to set the value of the Row and field in tMap. Use the Expression builder feature.